# setText() and setProgress() not updating in ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, progress-bar, textview

**My app**
uses a `ViewPager` and `Fragements`. Each `Fragment` shows a `ListView` with `CheckBoxes`, a `ProgressBar` and a `TextView`. If 3 out of 6 `CheckBoxes` are getting checked the `ProgressBar` and `TextView` should update to 3%.

**The Problem**
The TextView and ProgressBar are not displaying the update properly. I logged the calculated progress value and the value of `tv.getText()` and `pb.getProgress()`. There are two problems:

1.) The progress value and the values of `tv.getText()` and `pb.getProgress()` 
  are not equal. The value returned by `tv.getText()` and `pb.getProgress()` are 
  always 3% too high or too low.
(And yes the values I pass to setProgress() and setText() are correct)

```
11-30 14:44:57.099 14230-14230/com.example..myapplication 
D/CheckBox: setProgressBar()
progress should be = 3%
progressBar is = 0%
progressText is = 0%

11-30 14:45:02.275 14230-14230/com.example..myapplication 
D/CheckBox: setProgressBar()
progress should be = 7%
progressBar is = 3%
progressText is = 3%
```

2.) The `TextView` and `ProgressBar` View are always displaying 0%.

I tried to fix this for hours and I can't even find a solution here on StackOverflow. What's going wrong?

**Fragment class**

```
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable 
    ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

    progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressText = view.findViewById(R.id.progressText);
    lv = view.findViewById(R.id.list_view_nahrungsmittel);
    dateTV = view.findViewById(R.id.changeDate);
    leftBTN = view.findViewById(R.id.changeDateBTNLeft);
    rightBTN = view.findViewById(R.id.changeDateBTNRight);
    backToTodayBTN = view.findViewById(R.id.backToTodayBTN);

    mDB = new DBHelper(getContext());  //hier oder main?
    items = MainActivity.getList();

    setBTN();
    setBackToTodayButton();
    setNumCheckedCB();
    setDateTV();
    setProgressBarFirstTime();
    setListAdapter();
    setListViewListener();
    setButtons();

    return view;
}

public void setProgressBar(int i) {
    Log.d("CheckBox", "setProgressBar()");
    progress = (int)(((float)i * 100f) / (float) MainActivity.getNumCB());
    Log.d("CheckBox", "progress should be = " + progress + "%" );
    Log.d("CheckBox", "progressBar is = " + progressBar.getProgress() + "%" );
    Log.d("CheckBox", "progressText is = " + progressText.getText() );
    progressBar.setProgress(progress);
    progressText.setText(progress + "%");
}
```

**ListAdapter**
sets the Listener for each CheckBox in the ListView, which calls the setProgressBar() method.

```
//Click on CB
    final DataHolder finalHolder1 = holder;
    holder.cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
         @Override
         public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
             if(buttonView.isPressed()) {
                 buttonView.setChecked(isChecked);

                 //Update Progress
                 int i = 0;
                 boolean[] stateCheckBox = mDB.getCheckBoxState(date, item.getTitle());
                 if(isChecked){
                     if(finalHolder1.cb1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && finalHolder1.cb2.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && finalHolder1.cb3.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ){
                        if(stateCheckBox[1] == false && stateCheckBox[2] ==false) { i = 3; }
                        else if (stateCheckBox[1] == false && stateCheckBox[2] ==true) { i = 2; }
                        else if (stateCheckBox[1] == true && stateCheckBox[2] ==true) { i = 1; }
                     }
                     else if (finalHolder1.cb1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && finalHolder1.cb2.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                         if (stateCheckBox[1] == false) { i = 2; }
                         else if (stateCheckBox[1] == true) { i = 1; }
                     }
                     else { i = 1; }
                 }
                 else { i = 1; }
                 updateNumCheckedCheckBoxes(date, isChecked, i);

                 //Update CB state
                 //Case1: Three CB in row, Left gets checked -> set all other right CB´s checked
                 if (isChecked) {
                     finalHolder1.cb2.setChecked(isChecked);
                     finalHolder1.cb3.setChecked(isChecked);
                     mDB.updateCheckBoxState(date, item.getTitle(), isChecked, isChecked, isChecked);
                 } else {
                     if (finalHolder1.cb2.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                         //Case2: Only one Cb in row, uncheck
                         mDB.updateCheckBoxState(date, item.getTitle(), isChecked, isChecked, isChecked);
                     } else if (finalHolder1.cb3.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                         //Case3: Two Cb in row, left gets unchecked
                         mDB.updateCheckBoxState(date, item.getTitle(), isChecked, !isChecked, !isChecked);
                     } else {
                         //Case4: Three CB, left gets unchecked
                         mDB.updateCheckBoxState(date, item.getTitle(), isChecked, !isChecked, !isChecked);
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     });

    holder.cb2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(buttonView.isPressed()) {
                buttonView.setChecked(isChecked);

                //Update Progress
                int i = 0;
                boolean[] stateCheckBox = mDB.getCheckBoxState(date, item.getTitle());
                if(isChecked){
                    if(finalHolder1.cb1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && finalHolder1.cb2.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && finalHolder1.cb3.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ){
                        if(stateCheckBox[2] ==false) { i = 2;}
                        else if (stateCheckBox[2] ==true) { i = 1;}
                    }
                    else if (finalHolder1.cb1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && finalHolder1.cb2.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) { i = 1; }
                }
                else {
                    if(finalHolder1.cb1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && finalHolder1.cb2.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && finalHolder1.cb3.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ){
                        if(stateCheckBox[0] ==false) { i = 1; }
                        else if (stateCheckBox[2] ==true) { i = 2; }
                    }
                    else if (finalHolder1.cb1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && finalHolder1.cb2.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                        if(stateCheckBox[0] == true) { i = 2; }
                        else if (stateCheckBox[0] == false) { i = 1;}
                    }
                }
                updateNumCheckedCheckBoxes(date, isChecked, i);

                //Update CB state
                //Case5: Second from the left CB gets checked -> set right CB checked
                if (isChecked) {
                    finalHolder1.cb3.setChecked(isChecked);
                    mDB.updateCheckBoxState(date, item.getTitle(), !isChecked, isChecked, isChecked);
                }
                //Case6: Second from the left CB gets unchecked -> set left CB unchecked
                else {
                    finalHolder1.cb1.setChecked(isChecked);
                    mDB.updateCheckBoxState(date, item.getTitle(), isChecked, isChecked, !isChecked);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    holder.cb3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(buttonView.isPressed()) {
                buttonView.setChecked(isChecked);

                //Update Progress
                int i = 0;
                boolean[] stateCheckBox = mDB.getCheckBoxState(date, item.getTitle());
                if(isChecked){ i = 1; }
                else {
                    if(finalHolder1.cb1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && finalHolder1.cb2.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && finalHolder1.cb3.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ){
                        if(stateCheckBox[0] == false && stateCheckBox[1] == false) { i = 1; }
                        else if (stateCheckBox[0] == false && stateCheckBox[1] ==true) { i = 2; }
                        else if (stateCheckBox[0] == true && stateCheckBox[1] == true) { i = 3; }
                    }
                }
                updateNumCheckedCheckBoxes(date, isChecked, i);

                //Update CB state
                //Case5: Right CB gets unchecked -> set all other left CB´s unchecked
                if (!isChecked) {
                    finalHolder1.cb2.setChecked(isChecked);
                    finalHolder1.cb1.setChecked(isChecked);
                    mDB.updateCheckBoxState(date, item.getTitle(), isChecked, isChecked, isChecked);
                }
                else {
                    //Case 6: 3CBs, only right CB gets checked
                    mDB.updateCheckBoxState(date, item.getTitle(), !isChecked, !isChecked, isChecked);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    //Click on Image Button
    holder.imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent(context , Statistic2Activity.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

private void updateNumCheckedCheckBoxes (String date, boolean isChecked, int i){
    mDB.updateNumCheckedCheckBoxes(date, isChecked, i);
    updateProgressBar(date);

}
```

Comment: Your listener doesn't call `setProgressBar()`.

Comment: it does. updateProgressBar() calls setProgressBar(). I forgot to add updateProgressBar() to the code sample. Otherwise the log messages from setProgressBar() wouldn‘t show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this in the setProgressBar() method fixed my problem:

```
progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
progressText = view.findViewById(R.id.progressText);
```